# EntityFramework TPT + table merge

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, entity-framework-5

I have error: "error 0114: Number of Properties in the Dependent and Principal Role in a relationship constraint must be exactly identical." on this code

```
  public abstract class UserBase
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid Guid { get; set; }     

        [Required]
        public string Name { get; set; }   
    }

    public class User : UserBase
    {
        public DateTime? BirthDate { get; set; }    
        public UserPassword Password { get; set; }        
    }

    public class Outsourcer : UserBase
    {
        public Guid OutsourcingCompanyGuid { get; set; }    
        public OutsourcingCompany OutsourcingCompany { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserPassword
    {
            [Key]
            public Guid UserGuid { get; set; }
            public User User { get; set; }

            public string Password { get; set; }
            public string Salt { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<UserBase> Users { get; set; }
        public DbSet<UserPassword> UserPasswords { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserBase>().ToTable("UserBase");
            modelBuilder.Entity<Outsourcer>().ToTable("Outsourcer");

            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("User");
            modelBuilder.Entity<User>().HasRequired(t => t.Password).WithRequiredPrincipal(t => t.User);
            modelBuilder.Entity<UserPassword>().ToTable("User");
        }
}
```

I want merge User and UserPassword into one table named "User". 
Code without line `modelBuilder.Entity<UserPassword>().ToTable("User");` works, but I get two difrent tables.

Comment: why you don't merge user and password in your model? it's a one to one relationship...

Comment: When accessing user table I do not want to get the password. I understand that this is made to implement a variety of ways. But I still want to know why this code does not work.